# cant add foreign key constraint, error 1215 in mysql workbench.

Tags: mysql, database

So this is my code, I cannot proceed because I am always getting that foreign key constraint error. I have checked the data type they are consistent. Where am I going wrong?. All the problem persists where foreign keys are required. i have just posted two tables here.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `44376936`.`AccountType`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `44376936`.`AccountType` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `44376936`.`AccountType` (
  `AccountTypeID` float NOT NULL,
  `AccountTypeName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AccountTypeDesc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AccountTypeInterestRate` FLOAT NULL,
  `AccountTypeServiceFee` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccountTypeID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `44376936`.`Account`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `44376936`.`Account` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `44376936`.`Account` (
  `AccountBSB` INT NOT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `AccountCurrentBalance` FLOAT NULL,
  `AccountType_AccountTypeID` Float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccountBSB`, `AccountNumber`, `AccountType_AccountTypeID`),
  INDEX `fk_Account_AccountType_idx` (`AccountType_AccountTypeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Account_AccountType`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AccountType_AccountTypeID`)
    REFERENCES `44376936`.`AccountType` (`AccountTypeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya why would you insert the data first? That shouldn't be necessary. If anything it's more likely to create problems. besides, who says any data even exists yet? I'd be interested to know the rationale for your suggestion.

Comment: Anim can you show us the exact full text of the error message please.

Comment: @ADyson this is suggested post taking a mysqldump and reimporting the dump

Comment: this might help you, https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya even if that's what's happening here, it's still not relevant to the issue. And adding data _before_ adding a constraint is risky in case the data violates the contraint, and makes it impossible to add the constraint for that reason. It's not a good suggestion IMO. If you have a reputable source which recommends this practice then please link to it, I am always happy to be corrected but AFAIK it's not a good idea.

Comment: @aDyson it says error code 1215. Cannot add foreign Key constraint. This is the only thing it says.

Comment: @AnimRahman ok no problem, thanks. I suggest you take a look at the answer below, and if that doesn't fix it then also the read the blog linked to by Mayank which has listed all the reasons why such an error might occur. You'll have to work through them and see what might apply to your scenario. But to me the answer below looks like it probably resolves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce

It comes from this instruction :

```
REFERENCES `44376936`.`AccountType` (`AccountTypeID`)
```

and the problem is the database name, probably because it begins with a number and not a letter.

This works :

```
REFERENCES `AccountType` (`AccountTypeID`)
```

So get rid of the database name. If you are running this without being on the `44376936` database, execute this instruction at the beginning of your script :

```
USE `44376936`;
```

[Rextester example](http://rextester.com/live/HISV40718)

Comment: I still get the same error. For example this code does not even create the Branch table. 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `44376936`.`Branch` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `44376936`.`Branch` (
  `BSB` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `BranchName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `BranchAdress` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `BranchPhone` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BSB`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '   ';

Comment: I dont see how this could be related. I have reproduced your original error in rextester and succeed to get rid of it by using the trick above. It should work if you do excatly what I did, and that's all i can say. If you have another error, this is unrelated.

Comment: I tried this one and ran it, it says Error(s), warning(s):

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails